# Creating new PlayN project in eclipse does not have java content-assist

Tags: eclipse, maven, playn

I created a new PLAYN project based on the "Generating a skeleton project with Eclipse" instructions on the wiki 
( found here: http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Generating_a_skeleton_project_with_Eclipse )

Everything was set up correctly but Eclipse doesn't recognize it as a java project so I lose the syntax checking, content assist, etc (I get run-time error dialog box when content assist tries to help) for java.

I get "compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project" followed by "The 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui.javaAllCompletionProposalComputer' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui' plug-in did not complete normally...".

Did I miss a step?  Is there a way to add it to the project?

I tried editing the .project to add a java nature but that really messed up the project structure constructed by maven.  (based on [How do Java and Maven builders work together in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832789/how-do-java-and-maven-builders-work-together-in-eclipse))

I tried adding a java builder to the project properties and looked adding a plug-in dependency in Maven but couldn't figure that out (I'm still learning Maven).

thanks.

Comment: i had a simmilar problem, and in the end I gave up on maven, and configured everything with ANT and the ant-maven plugin...

Comment: I did solve this issue, but it some time ago and I don't remember the exact steps. In the completion popup, you can configure I think. In my case, there was something (Mylyn?) stopping the proper suggestions, and some other option missing. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are writing code in the [project-name]-core Eclipse project rather than the [project-name] Eclipse project.

Comment: This suggestion helped me to get it fixed. I've been editing the wrong .java file.

Answer (score 1):

Searching around internet I found several reasons for this error. In my case the problem was that the project's nature was not Java.

To fix that:

- close the project
- edit file .project on project's root
- Add the following line to  section:

  org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature
- Done. Open your project and code assist works correctly now.