# Does Project->Build Project in Eclipse with m2e include any Maven goal by default?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Update: Does Project->Build Project in Eclipse with m2e include any Maven goal by default?

Does including
 `<build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
 </build>`
into POM.xml change the action of  "Build Project" and add the second compilation also by Maven Builder?

[image: builders]

When the flag Project-> Build automatically is checked in Eclipse two builders do differnt things when I update a project. As far as I understand:

1) Maven Project Builder gets dependencies when I update pom.xml.
2) One of these two builders compiles code when I change it.

a. Which builder compiles code? As far as I know Maven has its own JAVA_HOME. And I can also attach any JRE to my Eclipse project. So JREs may be different.

b. What other actions does Maven Builder do and when (when updating pom or code)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Java and Maven builders work together in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832789/how-do-java-and-maven-builders-work-together-in-eclipse)

Comment: And which builder works first when choose Project->Build Project?

Comment: The topmost builder comes first. To change the order select a builder an press _Up_ or _Down_. If the `.classpath` is edited by the _Maven Project Builder_ then this change triggers another build, so the _Java Builder_ sees the correct dependencies.

Comment: Thanks you. Does including  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>  into POM.xml adds the second compilation?

Answer (score 1):

- The Maven builder will build according to the goal which is defined to it and check the correctness of your dependencied by the pom file.
- The Java builder compiles the code and automatically and responsible about ther correctness of your Eclipse project.